# Check which platform is user using while he is on a website

Tags: javascript, web

I have a website. I want to know which user is he using if he has come to my website. For eg. iOS, Android, Windows phone, Windows pc. Specifically for iOS, I want to check if he is on an iPhone or now

Comment: https://github.com/ded/bowser

Comment: The User Agent string should tell you but be aware that it can be spoofed or omitted. If you're gathering stats it's fine, but if you're relying on it for browser sniffing then you could be storing up trouble.

Comment: Actually one of the features is not compatible with iOS. I just want them to be aware that this won't work on your phones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

javaScript:
 http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2011/11/detecting-mobile-devices-   with-javascript/.

```
  var isMobile = {
  Android: function() 
  {
       return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
   },
   BlackBerry: function()
  {
      return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
  },
  iOS: function()  
   {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
   },
  Opera: function() 
  {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
  },
 Windows: function() 
 {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
 },
 any: function()
 {
     return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() ||    isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
}
```

};

Answer (score 1):

```
library for detecting mobile clients here: http://mobiledetect.net

  include 'Mobile_Detect.php';
  $detect = new Mobile_Detect();

 // Check for any mobile device.
  if ($detect->isMobile())
   // mobile content
 else
```